# Sequelize literal attribute as boolean

Tags: mysql, node.js, boolean, sequelize.js, literals

When using a literal with Sequelize (v4 or v5) you cannot tell Sequelize to cast your value to boolean directly, is it possible to cast it in another way ?

Example :

```js
models.Publication.findAll({
            attributes: {
                include: [
                    [models.sequelize.literal("IFNULL((Select 1 from `like` where like.publicationId = `Publication`.`publicationId` and userId = " + req.decoded.userId + "), 0)"), 'liked'],
                ]
            },
            order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
        })
```

I could use the map function but I have a lot of data and it will slow my function.

Comment: Why don't you cast it in a literal itself?

Comment: @Anatoly How could I cast the literal itself ? I need a boolean (which in MySQL gives a TINYINT(1)) and apparently sequelize uses the model definition to cast it as a boolean